# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString not working?

Tags: objective-c

The first NSLog returns the correct URL After that I get this error.

> 2013-07-06 21:07:56.622 Social App[69682:14003] -[NSURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a4ae10

```
   videoURL = [[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"streamURL"];
    NSLog(@"URL; %@", videoURL);

    videoURL = [videoURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" withString:@""];
    videoURL = [videoURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&feature=youtube_gdata_player" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"URL; %@", videoURL);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: go ahead and convert your NSURL to a string with absoluteString or whatever it is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the third line it seems you are sending a `NSString` message to a `NSURL`. That is why the second `NSLog` says `[NSURL stringBy...]` and `unrecognized selector`, since the `NSURL` class does not have a method named `stringBy...`.

What you have to do is insert this line between the second and third lines:

```
NSString* videoString = [videoURL absoluteString];
```

And then substitute `videoURL` with `videoString` on the lines where you call `stringBy...`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `videoURL.absoluteString`.

Right now you are trying to use a `NSString` method ( `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` ) on a `NSURL`, that of course won't work. `absoluteString` will get you a `NSString` to work with.

Answer (score 0):

`videoURL` is a `NSURL`

use:

```
stringUrl = [videoURL absoluteString];
```

then use `stringurl` for further operations like `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`